# Header file not found in XDP source compiled in Go program

Tags: c, linux, go, ebpf, xdp-bpf

My XDP module compiles by itself, but compilation within the context of a Go program fails because it can't find `bpf/bpf_helpers.h` file. Here's the code leading up the problem:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    bpf "github.com/iovisor/gobpf/bcc"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/include/bcc/compat
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lbcc
#include <bcc/bcc_common.h>
#include <bcc/libbpf.h>
void perf_reader_free(void *ptr);
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    // Get the source code from disk
    source, err := ioutil.ReadFile("xdp/collect_ips.c")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Cannot read collect_ips.c")
    }

    // Compile module
    module := bpf.NewModule(string(source), []string{
        "-Wall",
        "-O2",
    })
    defer module.Close()

    // Load module
    fn, err := module.Load("collect_ips", C.BPF_PROG_TYPE_XDP, 1, 65536) // Problem happens here

    // ...
```

The Go program compiles fine, but I when I run the program, I get this:

```
/virtual/main.c:2:10: fatal error: 'bpf/bpf_helpers.h' file not found
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
9 warnings and 1 error generated.
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x4b23d4]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/iovisor/gobpf/bcc.(*Module).Close.func1(0x203000)
        /home/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/iovisor/gobpf@v0.2.0/bcc/module.go:132 +0x14
github.com/iovisor/gobpf/bcc.(*Module).Close(0x0)
        /home/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/iovisor/gobpf@v0.2.0/bcc/module.go:132 +0x36
panic({0x4da720, 0x59ec60})
        /usr/lib/go-1.17/src/runtime/panic.go:1038 +0x215
github.com/iovisor/gobpf/bcc.(*Module).Load(0x0, {0x4ef9f2, 0xb}, 0x2, 0x2, 0x8001)
        /home/me/go/pkg/mod/github.com/iovisor/gobpf@v0.2.0/bcc/module.go:202 +0x36
main.main()
        /home/me/go/src/code.squarespace.net/net/prism-stream/cmd/server/main.go:35 +0x1b7
```

This problem is happening because of my XDP module because if I comment out this header file in the C source, the error moves to a different header file.

I think this is happening because of `bpf_helpers.h` does not exist here `https://github.com/iovisor/gobpf/tree/master/elf/include`. If this is the issue, is there a way to use the header file from `/usr/include/bpf`?

If I take out `bpf_helpers.h` from the XDP code, I get an error complaining about the use of `SEC` in my code:

```
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") addr_map = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_LRU_HASH,
    .key_size = sizeof(struct addr_desc_struct),
    .value_size = sizeof(long),
    .max_entries = 4096
};
```

I copied the macro for `SEC` from `bpf_helpers.h` to my code, but I then get `error: variable has incomplete type 'struct bpf_map_def'`. I also use `bpf_map_lookup_elem()` and `bpf_map_update_elem()`, which are defined in the `bpf/` directory.

Comment: Are you sure you need to include `bpf_helpers.h` when you run your XDP program with gobpf/bcc? I believe bcc should pull all the definitions for you already. It's necessary if you compile with just `clang`, but not from gobpf/bcc I'd say. What is the error you get if you comment out this include in your XDP source?

Comment: It looks like I do need it, primarily because I use ```BPF_MAP_TYPE_LRU_HASH```. Is there a way to load the .o file from Go? This is what the C++ examples do.

Comment: Sorry I don't know, don't have much experience with gobpf myself.

Comment: I tried out [goebf](https://github.com/dropbox/goebpf), but I was not able to load the .o file. Which language do you recommend using with BPF/XDP?

Comment: Anything from the list at https://ebpf.io/projects#ebpf-libraries should be a good choice. Gobpf should work too but not sure how to fix your program. Maybe open an issue on their GitHub repo to ask?

Comment: I ended up using the one from cilium, although libbpfgo sounds interesting. I'll post an answer, because XDP program has to be slightly different than if you load it using xdp-loader.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [eBPF library from Cilium](https://github.com/cilium/ebpf). Here's an example program that loads .o file to an interface, waits for 10 seconds, and prints whatever is in the BPF map.

You have to make sure your XDP function has `SEC("xdp")` before it. Whereas if you load the program using `xdp-loader`, you can pass whatever you want to `SEC` as long as it's different from the name of the function.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/cilium/ebpf"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "github.com/vishvananda/netlink"
    "time"
)


func main() {
    var objects struct {
        XCProg  *ebpf.Program `ebpf:"collect_ips"` // Name of function containing the XDP program
        XCMap   *ebpf.Map     `ebpf:"addr_map"` // Name of the map 
    }

    spec, err := ebpf.LoadCollectionSpec("dist/collect_ips.o")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("ebpf.LoadCollectionSpec", err)
    }

    if err := spec.LoadAndAssign(&objects, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("ebpf.LoadAndAssign", err)
    }

    link, err := netlink.LinkByName("enp0s8")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("netlink.LinkByName", err)
    }

    err = netlink.LinkSetXdpFdWithFlags(link, objects.XCProg.FD(), 2)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("netlink.LinkSetXdpFdWithFlags")
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second*10)

    var keyBytes, valueBytes []byte

    iterator := objects.XCMap.Iterate()

    if iterator == nil {
        log.Fatalln("nil iterator")
    }

    for iterator.Next(&keyBytes, &valueBytes) != false {
        fmt.Printf("%x: %x", keyBytes, valueBytes)
    }

    defer objects.XCProg.Close()
    defer objects.XCMap.Close()
}
```